# selectedRegionTransform to handle onClick on Blueprint JS Table cell

Tags: blueprintjs

I´m trying to capture onClick events on cells in Blueprints JS-table. My goal is to trigger a method in a sibbling component that will show info about the selected (clicked) row in the table.

When googling the subject I found this [pull request](https://github.com/palantir/blueprint/pull/635) where the contributor comment from `themadcreator` hint´s to use `selectedRegionTransform`. He also refers to an example

> If you want to click a row, you should use a
>   selectedRegionTransform. This will allow drag-select and multi-select to
>   remain intact. There is an example in the PR preview page that does this.

Sadly, I can not find that example.

In my component I have these two methods (a bit simplified)

```
test(a,b) {
    console.log(a,b)
}

render() {
    return(
        <Table numRows={this.state.data.length} selectedRegionTransform={this.test}>
            <Column name="Title" cellRenderer={this.renderTitleCell} />
        </Table>
    )
}
```

This works in the sense that `log(a,b)` in the method `test` shows me two objects. One with grid coordinates and one with mouse event info. Then it breaks with this message.

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'cols' of undefined
at Function../node_modules/@blueprintjs/table/lib/esm/regions.js.Regions.getRegionCardinality (regions.js:97)
at Table._this.styleMenuRegion (table.js:259)
...
```

I´m sure it´s because I don´t know how to use `selectedRegionTransform` and therefor need som help.

I want the table to respond to events as normal. All I need is a hook to trigger my own function along with the normal functionality of the table.

Can someone please help me understand how this is done? Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are getting that error because `selectedRegionTransform` expects that you return a new `IRegion` object. This function allows you to intercept your current region selection and change it before it is rendered. In my case I have used it to convert a cell selection into a row selection.

```
selectedRegionTransform={(e) => {
    return {
        rows: e.rows
    }
}}
```

Note: you can also return `cols` to specify what columns you want to select.

Comment: Wow, a late but appreciated answer, I'll see if I can find and shake life into that old project =)